# can not find dependency created by maven nar plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-nar-plugin

I have created a jni project with java code (native methods) and C code.

The maven nar plugin produces both a jar file with only java code and a nar file with the proper native code as it should.

However when I want to reference this project/module from another project I get an error that the dependency is not found. Upon inspection of my local repository I notice that I only have nar files for both the java code & native code. How can I reference this dependency and will it automatically include the native code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be [referencing the dependency](http://duns.github.com/maven-nar-plugin/narDependencies.html) using `<type>nar</type>`.

Comment: Odd that I missed that because I do remember trying that. Oh well, it works now. Downloading the attached native nar is failing now as that seems to be another problem that I have to tackle.